# How to group product by category on list view by LinQ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by

I'm a newbiew asp.net mvc !

I'm having a list view to display Products:

```
Id  CateId CateName
1   2      Cate-B
|__ Product-B  
2   1      Cate-A
|__ Product-A
3   1      Cate-A
|__ Product-C
```

but now I want to display a list view group product by category like below. How can I do it ?

```
Id  CateId CateName
1   2      Cate-B
|__ Product-B
2   1      Cate-A
|__ Product-B
|__ Product-C
```

this is my code:

```
        public IQueryable<MyGroup> GetAllProduct()
    {
        var query = (from c in _categoryRepository.Table()
                     join p in _productRepository.Table() on c.Id equals p.CateId
                     select new MyGroup
                     {
                         Categories= c,
                         Products = p

                     }).ToList();

        return query.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @RahulSingh I have added my code.

Comment: Whatever code you have posted, I can't find any resemblance with that of your table, where you are fetching values like `Id, CateId, CateName`?

Comment: Sorry @RahulSingh I have edited my code like my question :)

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if its fine.

Comment: @RahulSingh how can I pass result of query to list view in razor ?

Comment: I have created an anonymous type, to pass it to view create a class and fill the same using query by replacing anonymous type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, this is what you need:-

```
var query = _categoryRepository.Table()
              .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.CateId, x.CateName })
              .Select(x => new
                   {
                      x.Key.Id,
                      x.Key.CateId,
                      x.Key.CateName,
                      ProductsNames = _productRepository.Table()
                                       .Where(p => p.CategoryId == x.Key.CateId)
                                       .Select(p => p.ProductName).ToList()
                   }).ToList();
```

Here, is a [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/goRrsW) for same where I have used LINQ-To-Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GroupBy method to group by the category Id.

Eg. Viewmodel.GroupBy(r => r.cateid)

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)